# Nested GET in node.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

```
    var app = express()



 app.get('/todos/filtered/:des', function (req, res) {
        var nestedVar = req.params.des;

    });
```

I get an error that `des` isnt defined. How can I refer to `:des` here as it is quite nested?

Comment: what is the uri to request to this route?

Comment: @morsecodist, no middleware, and nothing else here

Comment: @PunNeng, I didnt understand. I access this through localhost:3000

Comment: I meant.. does it look like localhost:3000/todos/filtered/filtered_text?

Comment: can you show the complete error and the url that you call... @Marodian

Comment: Is this all the code you have? Or just a snippet of it? @PunNeng the route would be http://localhost:3000/todos/filtered/:des

Comment: @JoshuaTerrill I meant the uri might not match the the route so I just wanted to see what the uri is when requrest to the server.

Comment: @PunNeng ah I see, good point. Where are you trying to access `:des`? From inside the callback or outside the callback, somewhere else in the code? This is why having a full snippet of code would be very helpful.